# Why doesn't this subclass of Fragment have a empty constructor? (Google iosched)

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, wear-os

The document of Fragment says:

> All subclasses of Fragment must include a public empty constructor.
>   The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed,
>   in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this
>   constructor to instantiate it. If the empty constructor is not
>   available, a runtime exception will occur in some cases during state
>   restore.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

But this class doesn't have a empty constructor. Why doesn't this class have empty constructor?
https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/Wearable/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/iowear/fragments/SubmitFragment.java

Comment: I think that is a sample for wearables, so it might have something to do with the slightly different framework on Wearables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it won't be able to be easily recreated by the container in a Fragment transaction, these managed classes are encoraged to keep the default constructor. For instance, restoring the state of a fragment, which is performed automatically.

It is not forbidden by the structure, you can add other constructors if you want, for instance, for using them during **Unit Tests**, but **ensure the keep the public default constructor available at application runtime**.

Comment: You are right. And you can use `setArguments(Bundle)` in customs constructors and use `getArguments()`. The system will re-set the arguments with the no-parameter constructor when re-creating.

Answer (score 1):

Because its super class (the class it extends) has a constructor which is public, therefore it's by all the subclasses.

Comment: But the Superclass is Fragment, and as the documentation states, Fragments can only have an empty constructor.

Comment: False, if you add a constructor to your class, no default constructor is created. You have to explicit the constructor that match `super();`

Comment: @Kevinrob is right. Furthermore I checked the wrong link. The class on the 2nd link does have a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this code is wrong. But I don't know a lot about wearable-like device. Maybe the SDK work differently with wear-device.

The problem with no-empty constructor only appear when the system kill(save) an `Activity` and recreate it. It would like to create an instance of the `Fragment` but can't.